# Barlett Window - Tri function

Tags: signal-processing

I'm trying to understand what is meant by the following equation:

> Bartlett Window (Triangle):
>
> $$w(n)=TRI\left(\frac{2n}N\right)$$

Basically, it's the $TRI$ function, since, mathematically I don't know how to represent this.

The other equation to solve this problem is:

> $$w(n)=\frac2{N-1}\left(\frac{N-1}2-\left|n-\frac{N-1}2\right|\right)$$

This confuses me also, because I know what $w(n)$ is the signal, but what calculation must be performed?

Comment: never heard of it. try Google, maybe some phrase from your text or notes will lead you to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [triangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), which is exactly what it sounds like.